# Typeorm query + socket

Tags: typeorm

I get an error. How do I make an update request in the database correctly?

> return await usedQueryRunner.query(query, parameters) // await is
> needed here because we are using finally
> TypeError: usedQueryRunner.query is not a function

```
socket.on("checkUserOnline", async (user: any) => {
    if (users[user]) {
      await db.query('UPDATE "user" SET is_online = $1 WHERE id = $2;', ['Y', user] ,(err ,res) => {
        if(err) throw err
        socket.emit("online", user);
      })
    } else {
      await db.query('UPDATE "user" SET is_online = $1 WHERE id = $2;', ['N', user] ,(err ,res) => {
        if(err) throw err
        socket.emit("offline", user);
      })
      socket.emit("offline", user);
    }
  });
```